# Best data type for large strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Currently i am setting it as varchar with a max length of 15000 - it is storing forum posts so they can vary in size a lot.
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [TEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) data type. It is more convenient if you want to store really big strings.

Comment: Blob is another option, if you want the server to pass the database back and forth verbatim, without worrying about charset issues.